# How to know whether I am at a straight road, a roundabout, or at a left or right turn, or a dead-end using Google Mapd SDK?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

We are building a product for visually impaired people for which we need to know what kind of road our user is on. At any kind of turn, we need to be able to specify whether it's a left or right turn, a T-shaped junction, a roundabout, or a dead end. We don't want a route from one place to another, just information about the road from only the current coordinates of the user.

We have looked up multiple APIs but haven't come across anything which is useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Directions API have this [steps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsLeg-steps) which is an array of steps denoting information about each separate step of the leg of the journey. But I'm not sure if this would fit your use case. If that's the case, filing a Feature Request would be good. See this link on how to do so: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to this that I can think of is the Roads API, which would return a list of snapped coordinates and place IDs of road segments. You could request place details for the closest place ID, and that road segment name could be a type indication (e.g. "Vernon Circle" being a roundabout). Alternatively you would have to analyse the shape of the coordinate array yourself.

[image: Roads API Inspector]

Source of image: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/inspector